# BSOD FLxHCIc after recovering from Sleep

Tags: bsod

My Asus laptop (N73S) crashes after recovering from sleep. Dump file analysis (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) indicates a problem with `FLxHCIc.sys` which is a driver for Fresco USB 3.0 driver.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browsed the web and found indication that Fresco 3.0 driver does not work together with some USB 2.0 devices plugged into the 3.0 port.

I disconnected a 2.0 device from the 3.0 port and sleep began working fine.

I hope there is a bugfix for this issue soon.